# Why rails minitest testcases are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

My posts_controller_Test.rb file:

```
# test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class PostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    def setup
       @post = Post.new
    end

    test 'should get index' do
        get :index
        assert_response :success
        assert_not_nil assigns(:posts)
    end
end
```

## My post_controller File

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @post = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @post }
        end
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_param)
        if @post.save
            redirect_to action: 'index'
        else
            render 'new'
    end
end
```

Why my `test cases` are failing? Is it because I have `authenticate_user!` condition? I also have `.yml` file and tried to test with it but after initializing with `.yml` data I am getting `RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.`

## yml file

```
one:
 data 2
 value: 3
 user_id: 1
 name: 'test'
```

.yml has everything what i have required in

```
params.require(:post).permit(:data, :value, :name) and obvious `user` for foreign key reference
```

## Edit -1

After the suggestion of inheriting with `ApplicationController`

Got this new error:

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Base

 app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

this is my line 3:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController::Base
```

## Edit-2

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
```

got this:

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you've inherited your controller from the wrong class.  Inherit from ApplicationController instead:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please look at `Edit-2` section

Comment: Now you've asked a completely different question.  If this solved your initial problem, mark this answer as accepted and open a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured out why it was not working and how to include `devise` session for user in test cases. 

But this time I am getting slightly different issue. Here is my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194778/how-to-run-minitest-for-controller-methods